# Abelian varieties by Moonen and van der Geer: proof of rigidity lemma

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties, schemes

I try to understand a reduction step in the proof of rigidity lemma as proved in Moonen's and van der Geer's [Abelian varieties](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&ei=r5ScXcvLBcelwQKqg62gBA&q=abelian%20varieties%20moonen&oq=abelian%20varieties%20moonen&gs_l=psy-ab.3...0.0..73045...0.0..0.0.0.......0......gws-wiz.0vlQ1CwvC98&ved=0ahUKEwiL3_Ld54zlAhXHUlAKHapBC0QQ4dUDCAo&uact=5) (Lemma 1.11 on page 12- if the link not work the draft version is online available):

Lemma.
Let $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ be algebraic varieties over a field $k$. Suppose that $X$
is complete. If $f : X × Y \rightarrow Z$ is a morphism with the property that, for some $y \in Y (k)$, the fibre $X \times_k \{y\}$ is mapped to a point $z \in Z(k)$ then $f$ factors through the projection $pr_Y : X \times_k Y → Y$.

The proof starts with reduction to $k=\bar{k}$. Why we can reduce to the case $k=\bar{k}$?

My naive first thought was, if $f_{\bar{k}}:X \times Y \times \bar{k} \to Z \times \bar{k}$ factors through the projection $Y \times \bar{k}$ then is looks to be possible to factor $f$ itself through $pr_Y$. It looked straightforward but now I come to decision that such easy argument don't work. Does somebody see what the authors had in mind doing this reduction?

Comment: Let $\Gamma \subseteq Y\times Z$ be the (scheme-theoretic) image of the graph $\Gamma_f \subseteq X\times Y\times Z$ with respect to the projection along $X$. The assertion of the lemma amounts to the statement that the projection $\Gamma\to Y$ is an isomorphism. This can be checked over $\bar k$.

Comment: You  refer to a faithful-flatness argument of $\bar{k}$
, i.e. $g: \Gamma\to Y$ isomorphism iff $g \times id_{\bar{k}}: \Gamma\ \times \bar{k} \to Y \times \bar{k}$ ?